# How to host for different company departments/clients on different IIS servers while sharing same ip address?

Tags: iis, hosting, iis-8, iis-8.5

I want to know whether I can accomplish this. If I can, then how?

I have a domain www.xyz.com. The different clients have their own virtual directory on IIS server. Eg:

```
www.xyz.com/client1
www.xyz.com/client2
www.xyz.com/client3
```

They all are hosted on the same box. Is it possible for me to seperate them out to different boxes and still be able to acheive the above?

That is, if I have 3 server boxes with ip address 123.456.789.10,123.456.789.11 and 123.456.789.12, can I have them all share the same website address? In the above scenario, client1 will be hosted on 123.456.789.10, client 2 will be hosted on 123.456.789.11 and client3 will be on 123.456.789.12.

Please let me know.

Thanks,

Kd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You can look into the web servers like Apache and nginx. They have modules mod_proxy which allows you to add Proxypass and ReverseProxypass rules.

Eg. 
Proxypass /client1 http://123.456.789.10/client1
ReverseProxypass /client1 http://123.456.789.10/client1

Proxypass /client2 http://123.456.789.11/client2
ReverseProxypass /client2 http://123.456.789.11/client2

and so on.

What you can also do is host this apache on server in DMZ zone and then proxypass to intranet servers hosting IIS sites.

Comment: Hi @Sahil, Thanks. Based on you answer I was able to find an IIS solution:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosag/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr/

Comment: Thats great!! Enjoy!